# Prove a topological basis

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove this:

Suppose $f: X\to Y$ is a map and $B$ is a topological basis on *Y*. Is {B: *f*(B) ∈ $B$} a topological basis on *X*?

My approach:

If x ∈ *X*, there exists y = f(x) ∈ f(B) for some f(B) ∈ $B$ since $B$ is a topological basis on *Y*, hence x ∈ B for some B which satisfies f(B) ∈ $B$.

Whether my approach is correct or it is not a topological basis? Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You attempt the impossible.
Counter example: 
$f: \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$, $x \mapsto 0$.
$\{ U : f(U) \in B \} = \{ U : \{0\} \in B \} = \emptyset$.

Revise the theorem you are trying to prove.
Do not put corrections in remarks.
Edit your reply so it reads as a complete theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you mean that the collection {B: f(B) ∈ B} is not a topological basis on X? Taking your counter example, I get B = {0} is a topological basis on Y, but B = {0} is not a topological basis on X. Am I correct now?

Comment: To the proposer: If $B\subset \Bbb R$ then $f(B)=\{0\}$ (which is not an open set) or $f(B)=\phi$ ( which happens only when $B=\phi).$ So $\{B: f(B)\in \mathcal B\}$ is $\phi $ if $\phi \not \in \mathcal B,$ or is $\{\phi\}$ if $\phi\in \mathcal B$.

Comment: @MingyunHU.  You have used B with two different meanings.   No, 
{empty set} is not a base for any space.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, let $\mathcal{B}$ be the base of rational intervals on $Y=\Bbb R$ and let $X=\Bbb R$ and let $f(x) \equiv 0$, the constant function. Then

$$\{B \subseteq \Bbb R: f[B] \in \mathcal{B}\}$$ is empty as $f[B]=\{0\}$ for any non-empty $B$ and both $f[\emptyset]=\emptyset$ as $\{0\}$ are not in $\mathcal{B}$. So the set does not form a base for any topology on $X$.